# How do you size the correct diodes for OR application of two power supplies?

Tags: diodes

How do you size the correct diodes needed to OR two 12V 1.25A power supplies? What voltage and current rating do the diodes need to be?

Comment: The voltage and current is determined by the voltage and current expected on these diodes at extreme conditions multiplied by a safety factor. You do the calculations.

Comment: Do not assume that both diodes will have exactly the same Vdrop across them unless it is proven by testing. This means that with diode summing junctions, 1 diode will dominate as the current source, even if by a tiny amount. The power supplies will not put out exactly the same voltage either. This will also cause one diode to dominate as the source of current.

Comment: AT EUGENE : Well, i do actually understand that the diodes need to be sized in relation to voltage and current at the extremes, the question is "How do you size them" and what is a good safety factor? You answer provided zero help. I am looking for a step by step guide which details the "how". If anybody can explain it, it would be appreciated. Professor responses like the above are not helpful at all.

Comment: At Sparky,256, how much of an issue is it if one diode dominates? and what does that mean long term? ie will one power supply be more likely to burn up before the other? thanks.

Comment: @Douglas - use the "@" symbol when referring to users such as what I have done with your name. If you do not, they will not be notified that a comment has been made to them.

Comment: Why are you trying to OR two power supplies? If it is because one supply does not supply enough current, then you may have issues, as Sparky pointed out. If you are just after redundancy, and a single supply provides adequate current, then you're fine, as long as you can tolerate those voltage variations caused by the diodes.

Comment: @Douglas, there is no one size fits all solution. You as the engineer for your system need to evaluate what the normal and maximum load currents are, if there are any transient load currents, what thermal environment the diode will operate in, what lifetime the product needs to have, etc., then choose a diode that meets your requirements.

Comment: @Mark im not actually ORing two separate power supplies i am actually ORing two control signals, each of those control signals being a 12V supply from the same power supply. ie I have two relays and the are controlled by other devices, the relays both have a NO contact and when the relays activate the 12V is passed through each of the respective relays. These control signals can be independent or on together and they control a contactor. So either 12v A or 12v B can operate the contactor. I want to have all the "control" signals there are 5 of them OR together with 1 O/P to contactor.

Comment: @ThePhoton i am looking for the theory behind how to calculate the correct size for a diode. I am not asking anybody to calculate it for me. thanks. 12V power supply with max current of 1.25A from the power supply. Does that mean it is  as simple as say 15V 2A diode or increase to 50V 3A Diode what the reasoning behind what diode to choose?

Comment: OK, it's not as simple as I first imagined. I think that you are OK, but that's assuming I really understand how you are doing this. A schematic would help.

Comment: For selection of diode http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-3/diode-ratings/ check this link.

Comment: @Douglas So you have said that the supply feeding the contactor coil is capable of 1.25A, but does the coil actually draw that much current or is it some lesser amount?

Answer (score 2):

Each diode needs to be specified to withstand the highest current thru it and the maximum reverse voltage across it.  This really should be obvious.

Keep in mind that the limiting factor for current may be power dissipation, not the maximum current spec of the diode.  You have to check both separately.  For example, let's say the maximum current you decide the diode will ever have to conduct in steady state is 5 A.  You check the datasheet and find that the forward drop at 5 A is 950 mV.  That means the diode will dissipate (5 A)(950 mV) = 4.75 W.

Now you look in the datasheet and see if the diode can safely dissipate 4.75 W in free air at your worst case ambient temperature.  If not, you need a different diode, a heat sink, or some form of cooling.